# Sync Multiple Devices Simultaneously With One Account

Tags: sync, google-account, multiple-devices

I've got a question regarding maintenance/management with multiple android devices on a single account. For example:

- A school has 30 android tablets.
- Teachers need all 30 devices updated
- The school has 1 account for all 30 devices

Is there a way to sync all of these simultaneously to the same account? iTunes U offers this functionality for iOS devices, but wanted to know if there are any similar services for android devices. Thanks for your help!

Comment: What do you want to sync?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That very much depends on how you understand the issue -- and what is intended. In this case, using a single account for all devices definitly has one big advantage: **Managing its apps** (installs/uninstalls).

If the devices are defined as "school use only" or even for a single class, same applies to the **calendar**: all class specific events can be defined here (in the accounts main calendar), so noone can say he forgot to write it down. For personal events, each user can add his/her own calendar easily -- so no problem with this either.

The **contacts**/address book can be seen the same way: it could hold the classes contacts, plus the teachers (as far as needed/wanted) -- which would make it easier to organize team work. As with calendars, it should be possible for each user to access her/his personal address book additionally (I never tried this, so I cannot tell for sure).

So to summarize: If I didn't mis-interprete your question, the answer should be a clear "Yes". I use multiple Android devices with the same Google account myself, and never had any problems with that.

Comment: Have you tried this and if so, have you run into any issues with maximum number of devices tied to the Google Account?