# Mass setup of Android devices

Tags: adb, 9.0-pie, multiple-devices, setup-wizard

I want to setup **the same account** on 300+ devices. I did that for 4 devices and I am tired.

Setting up new device includes:

1. manually doing all ok/next/skip choices
2. connecting to WiFi + installing updates
3. manually typing GMail + password
4. **MOST PROBLEMATIC** confirming new device by tapping two-digit number on the first device where this account was added.

Questions:

- Is there some automated solution?
- Is it possible to at least **turn off confirmation of new device** completely?

Comment: Search for "Samsung KNOX Mobile Enrollment (KME)" or "Google: Android Zero-Touch". But the latter requires devices that are enabled for zero touch which means you have to buy special devices that support zero touch. Regarding 300 devices in one account please read this: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/42506/2241

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Your question lacks some essential details, like: are all the 300 devices identical (i.e. same manufacturer/model)? Is a custom recovery available (so you could eg. easily use Nandroid backup/restore)? There is a special name for that kind of management software (which just eludes me), and we already have some related questions I cannot find without the term :( But as Robert wrote: the limit at Google for multiple devices per account is much lower than 300. Kick out Google and use F-Droid to avoid that problem :)

Comment: I've just added the [tag:multiple-devices] tag to your question, please invesitgate; especially related questions like [Clone and distribute Android 4 device with preloaded applications](/questions/32687/16575) // [Copying and remotely deploying a build across multiple devices](/q/174662/16575) // [Best Practise for deploying a clone image across 200 android tablets](/q/65140/16575) // [Bulk Android Device Provisioning This question links to the current page](/q/136172/16575) // [clone a Phone then flash image on other phones?](/q/127952/16575)