# How to handle Play store accounts in a medium sized company

Tags: google-play-store, google-account

What is the best way to handle Play Store in a medium company where it is not needed a google account for each user?

We have about 30 users with Android, they don't have and don't need a google account, the only problem we are facing is to install and keep updated all the apps.
I don't like the solution to let them register with a new google user account because so they will start using google address-book, mail, drive and not the official tools of the company.

Comment: You need a Google Account for downloading apps from Play Store and you can't use one account for all because of the device limitation: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/42506/is-there-a-maximum-number-of-devices-allowed-on-a-google-play-account

Comment: You are looking for MDM (Mobile Device Management) solutions. Asking for which one meets your needs, comparison etc is off-topic AFAIK

Answer (score 0):

Either use an MDM -mobile device management- or send them link of the APKs files through whatsapp-telegram or gmail.

Comment: currently I'm sending apk, but applications will not update