# Help need a way to know how to do bulk updates across multiple devices

Tags: updates, multiple-devices

I manage a bunch of android devices and I was wondering if there is an easy way to do bulk updates when a new release comes out. Also would like to know if I can block certain devices from being updated at all?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sync Multiple Devices Simultaneously With One Account](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/14758/sync-multiple-devices-simultaneously-with-one-account)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's not. You have to manually accept evey software update from every device. Imagine how big of a security problem it would be if you could do that remotely.

Of course you can ignore updates. They'll ask you for confirmation to install them, so you can just say no and be done with it (recent versions will allow you to block the notification if you don't want to see it).
Some ROMs even have the option to only check for updates manually, so you don't even need to know there's one available.